# triggers using multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I Have three tables

ms_seller table(seller_id - primary key)

```
seller_id  seller_status vacation_mode
   50             0            1
```

ms_product Table(product_id - primary key)

```
product_id    seller_id
     9           50
     2           50
```

product table

```
product_id     date_modified
       2         2017-01-06 16:13:27
       9         2017-01-06 16:13:27
```

My question is

if i am updating seller status or vacation_mode in ms_seller table then according to seller_id 50 , we will pick product_id from ms_product table then according to product_id 2 and 9, I have to update date modified by today date in product table

I am trying this but getting error

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_vacation_mode
ON oc_ms_seller.vacation_mode
AFTER UPDATE
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE oc_product p
    SET p.date_modified = NOW()
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM oc_ms_seller ms join oc_ms_product mp ON ms.seller_id= mp.seller_id);

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON oc_ms_seller.vacation_mode
AFTER UPDATE
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE oc_product' at line 2
```

thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The error message you received comes from the fact that you tried to declare the trigger on **field** (`oc_ms_seller.vacation_mode`), however, triggers are applicable to **tables**.

See MySQL documentation on [create trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) for details:

> ```
> CREATE
>     [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
>     TRIGGER trigger_name
>     trigger_time trigger_event
>     ON **tbl_name** FOR EACH ROW
>     [trigger_order]
>     trigger_body
> ```

However, in your trigger you should be using the `NEW.fieldname` reference in the where criteria of the update statement, otherwise the update will change all matching records.